# why can't I instantiate object of same class in class defintion

Tags: c++

I want to know why can't I instantiate an object of class inside that class definition.

e.g. In below code I get error as
"field 'a' has incomplete type"

but in template class C there is no such error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template < template <typename> class TT> class X
{
};

template < typename T> class C
{
    C no;
};

class obj
{
    public:
     obj a;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually tried to instantiate `C` then, yes, you'd get the same error. Class templates generally don't cause compilation errors: instantiating them to become classes does:

```
template <typename T>
class C
{
    C no;
};

int main()
{
    C<int> c;  // error: 'C<T>::no' has incomplete type
}
```

An instance of a class cannot contain an instance of itself; that would require infinite memory. A `C<int>` would contain a `C<int>` which would contain a `C<int>` which would contain a `C<int>`…

More formally, it is therefore impossible to determine the size of `C<int>`, and that's the problem the standard uses to ban this program.

Answer (score 1):

Template one had also result into an error would you try to instantiate that template. You are not getting the error as compiler proceeds with instantiation in two phases.

1) It would check templates for *syntax errors* and flag error for any inconsistencies.

2) When you instantiate it, it would check if all operations have well defined semantics on provided argument.

You have passed 1, but not tried 2.

Answer (score 0):

That will cause infinite recursive calls to constructor of class (C in this case). So this is not allowed; you can use pointer or reference of same type as class as data member of the same class.